# Combinding serial events into a signal string

Tags: python

I wonder if someone can help me out?
I am reading one line at a time from the serial data on a pi in python.

```
while True:
    try:
        ser_bytes= ser.readline()
        event = (ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8"))
        
        print(event)
    
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

The data comes in the following format.

Initialize (one time event)
Name
Location
Type
Time/date

Name
Location
Type
Time/date

Name
Location
Type
Time/date

I would like to combine all 4 into a single string (Name-Location-Type-Time/date).

What would be the neatest way of achieving this?

Comment: Are those blank lines added for clarity in this post, or are they present in the data?

Comment: No the blank lines are present at the end of the data package.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this since there's no [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but it should work fine:

```py
ser.readline()  # toss out the "initialize" event
lines = []
while True:
    for _ in range(4):
        new_event = []
        try:
            ser_bytes = ser.readline()
            new_event.append(ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8"))
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

    lines.append("-".join(new_event))
```

Basically just running a for loop which reads every four lines, joins them in the `Name-Location-Type-Time/date` format specified in the question, then adds that new string to an accumulator.